# Live kernel patching in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, rhel, kernel, linux-kernel, patch

I am trying to see the advantages & disadvantages of live kernel patching over a newly built kernel with intended patches. I read live kernel patching uses `ftrace`'s framework. Since `ftrace` keep hooks on the functions and redirect to the new function, will that be an overhead and will it not affect the time taken to call that function?

Comment: aren't old functions also called via a hook?